# Website crashes on single network but works everywhere else

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, database

Can a old version of jquery (specifically a javascript auto refresh code) crash a website for a single user/local network?

I have a small/simple MySQL database with PHP coded site to insert and retrieve data for internal (non-public) use.  It was developed over 4 years ago and still uses jquery-1.2.6.min.js and have had no problems until the past month.  Now the site is very random on the operation but only affects the local networks the user I developed it for.  It is not a browser crash such as when it goes down the site is unavailable on any computer in the network. Switch to a hotspot or a different building and all works as designed.

I don’t have any reason to think it is website or hosting problem (have talked to hosting support 3 times) but I am trying to cover my bases as the network engineers and ISP tech support are all scratching their heads.

I have used two instances of an auto refresh script 1) to show current time to the user and 2) to refresh the screen with new database content every 15 seconds.

An example on one of the two refresh scripts:

```
<script type=“text/javascript”>    
function load_content({ $(‘#db_content’).load(‘ac_data.php’).hide().show();} 
setInterval(‘load_content()’, 15000);

<div id=“db_content”>
<?php require ‘ac_data.php’;?
</div>
```

Is there any remote chance the code could be to blame since the site has not been updated since original development?  I am merely looking for ammo to put the ball back in the network teams court but if there is any chance my code could cause a hang up then I would like to be able to fix it.

Comment: I assume the server is outside the local network you're talking about? It sounds like your server decides to no longer serve new incoming requests from the external IP address of the local network. This can have several reasons: Too many requests, a database overload/blockade, etc. The best place to start your investigation is in the logs of the server.

Comment: Replace all smart quotes `“` and `”` by straight quotes `"`, and all `‘` and `’` by `'`.

Comment: Any http response ? 500, 400, 200? Network error?

Comment: Regarding the http response ... I haven’t been able to be on site when the problem occurs...when ever I go check it out it is working fine and then it stops later when I am not there.

All the quotes are correct in my code ... I just had to retype this on this question (vs copy/paste) and that is how my tablet typed them.  In the coding software they are straight quotes.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the site/database is hosted by GoDaddy.  I will look into the server logs as I was concerned the reload script may be causing a error (too many requests).  I have run the site on two different machines outside the problem network for over 12 hours with no problems.  The network guys are trying to get me to transfer everything to a different domain/hosting plan to see if a server change within GoDaddy will solve anything.  So, I am in the process of upgrading to cPanel with GoDaddy which will change the IP address of the server.  This should determine if the IP/server is the problem.